# consulta em 2 tabelas mesmo tempo

Tags: query

boa noite, pessoal, preciso de ajuda em uma consulta 2 tabelas if existe id na segunda aparece preço se não aparece preço da primeira tabela..

exemplo

tabela1                                           tabela2

----------------                    --------------------------------

id    | descricao    | preço      id  |   dtini   |   dtfim        | preço

17    | pao de sal   | 9,00       20  |   26/10/2017 | 30/10/2017  | 1,99

18    | bolo         | 10,80      17  | 26/10/2017  | 10/11/2017   | 6,10

20    | Quiabo       | 2,99

23    | Tomate       | 3,50

de modo que quando execultar a consulta resulte desta forma

tabela1

---

id      | descricao       | preço

17      | pao de sal      | 6,10

18      | bolo            | 10,80

20      | Quiabo          | 1,99

23      | Tomate          | 3,50

de modo que vou dar um select na tabela1 e listar tudo mas se a id existir na tabela2 pregar o preço da tabela2, se não existir manter o preço da tabela1..

Quem puder ajudar...

pode ser em postgres, fb,, mysql.

Answer (score 3):

Então temos duas tabelas:

Table1:

```
|--------------------------------|
|id      | descricao     | preço |
|--------------------------------|
|1       |Pão de Mel     | 15    |
|2       |Pão Frances    | 7     |
|--------------------------------|
```

E tenho a tabela 2:

Table2:

```
|--------------------------------|
|id      | descricao     | preço |
|--------------------------------|
|1       |Pão de Mel     | 50    |
|--------------------------------|
```

A sua regra de negócio é:

> de modo que vou dar um select na tabela1 e listar tudo mas se a id
>   existir na tabela2 pregar o preço da tabela2, se não existir manter o
>   preço da tabela1

E eu fiz, e testei a solução:

```
SELECT t1.descricao, if(t2.preco is null, t1.preco, t2.preco) 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

O resultado foi:

```
|--------------------------------|
|id      | descricao     | preço |
|--------------------------------|
|1       |Pão de Mel     | 50    |
|2       |Pão Frances    | 7     |
|--------------------------------|
```

Ele pegou o preço do Pão de mel da segunda tabela.:)

Comment: preciso de mais uma ajuda... na tabela 2 os itens tem uma vigência de promoção, dtinicio e dtfim ... qdo coloco "where b.dtinicio <= current_date and b.dtfim >= current_date " só aparece os produtos que estão contido na tabela 2.. meu código ta assim ---                                                                                                         select a.prd_codigo_barras Codigo, a.prd_descricao,
 iif(b.preco is null,  a.preco_atual, b.preco) from cap_produto a
 left join promoii b on b.barras = a.prd_codigo_barras  where b.dtinicio <= current_date and b.dtfim >= current_date